# Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping

Tags: c#, math, complex-numbers, integral

I have written some code to experiment with the Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping.

The basics for Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping can be found on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz%E2%80%93Christoffel_mapping).

```
namespace Conformal
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Numerics;

    // There is still some bugs, but not sure what is that ...
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static Complex Integrand(Complex input)
        {
            // [(w - 50)(w + 50)]^(-2/3)
            Complex inside = (input - 50) * (input + 50);
            return Complex.Pow(inside, -2.0 / 3.0);
            // Experiment, let integrate w = z instead and see if the output make sense
            // The good thing about trapezoidal rule is that its result is *exact* for linear function, so we can check if the answer make sense
            // Experiment passed, it does indeed give us what we wanted
            // return input;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Tuple<Complex, Complex>> TrapezoidReal(Complex integrateSrc, Complex integrateDst, int numIntervals, Func<Complex, Complex> f)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(integrateSrc, (Complex)0);
            double N = (double)numIntervals;
            double range = integrateDst.Real - integrateSrc.Real;
            double delta = range / N;

            Complex sum = f(integrateSrc) * 0.5 * delta;
            for (int n = 1; n <= numIntervals; n++)
            {
                Complex current = new Complex(integrateSrc.Real + (n / N) * range, integrateSrc.Imaginary);
                Complex eval = f(current);
                sum += eval * 0.5 * delta;
                yield return Tuple.Create(current, sum);
                sum += eval * 0.5 * delta;
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Tuple<Complex, Complex>> TrapezoidImag(Complex integrateSrc, Complex integrateDst, int numIntervals, Func<Complex, Complex> f)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(integrateSrc, (Complex)0);
            double N = (double)numIntervals;
            double range = integrateDst.Imaginary - integrateSrc.Imaginary;
            double delta = range / N;

            Complex sum = f(integrateSrc) * new Complex(0, 0.5 * delta);
            for (int n = 1; n <= numIntervals; n++)
            {
                Complex current = new Complex(integrateSrc.Real, integrateSrc.Imaginary + (n / N) * range);
                Complex eval = f(current);
                sum += eval * new Complex(0, 0.5 * delta);
                yield return Tuple.Create(current, sum);
                sum += eval * new Complex(0, 0.5 * delta);
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This avoid evaluating the integrand at the poles
            double shift = 0.1;

            // The program implements the Schwarz-Christoffel Mapping
            // The function build a conformal mapping that maps the upper 
            // half plane to a triangle

            // The base for the integration is (-100, 0)
            // We create a grid with real = (-100, 100), imag = (0, 200)
            // The grid is divided into 10 lines for simplicity
            // The numerical integration is done using trapezoidal rule

            Complex point_o = new Complex(-100 + shift, 0 + shift);
            Complex point_x = new Complex(100 + shift, 0 + shift);
            Complex point_y = new Complex(-100 + shift, 200 + shift);

            // First, build the X and Y axis
            var xAxis = TrapezoidReal(point_o, point_x, 10000, Integrand);
            var yAxis = TrapezoidImag(point_o, point_y, 10000, Integrand);

            // Sample every 1,000 elements for the marks
            var xMarks = Sample(xAxis, 1000);
            var yMarks = Sample(yAxis, 1000);

            //PrintPoints(xAxis);
            //PrintPoints(yAxis);

            // Build the horizontal grid lines
            foreach (var yMark in yMarks)
            {
                var imag = yMark.Item1.Imaginary;
                var gridPoints = Sample(TrapezoidReal(new Complex(-100 + shift, imag), new Complex(100 + shift, imag), 10000, Integrand).Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Item1, t.Item2 + yMark.Item2)), 100);
                PrintPoints(gridPoints);
            }

            // Build the vertical grid lines
            foreach (var xMark in xMarks)
            {
                var real = xMark.Item1.Real;
                var gridPoints = Sample(TrapezoidImag(new Complex(real, 0 + shift), new Complex(real, 200 + shift), 10000, Integrand).Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Item1, t.Item2 + xMark.Item2)), 100);
                PrintPoints(gridPoints);
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Tuple<Complex, Complex>> Sample(IEnumerable<Tuple<Complex, Complex>> xAxis, int every)
        {
            return xAxis.Where((t, i) => i % every == 0);
        }

        private static void PrintPoints(IEnumerable<Tuple<Complex, Complex>> gridPoints)
        {
            foreach (var gridPoint in gridPoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", gridPoint.Item1.Real, gridPoint.Item1.Imaginary, gridPoint.Item2.Real, gridPoint.Item2.Imaginary);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The full source code can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/cshung/MiscLab/tree/master/Conformal).

The code is basically a simplified implementation of the trapezoidal method applied on the integral. I based the integral at the lower left corner at (-100, 0), built the two axis, and then march upward and forward for the grid lines and print out the coordinates.

The generated graph is expected to look like this:

[image]

But in reality, it looks like this:

[image]

What else can I do to diagnose what goes wrong?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: I did, the code does generate a bunch of numbers, not sure what to look for.

No overflow happened (most arithmetic are done in double, and number just ranged around 1)

Not sure how to detect underflow.

Because the lines does run out of the triangle, I made a conditional breakpoint when eval imaginary part get negative, but it seems legitimate when I compute the values myself.

Tips on how to debug can be really helpful

Comment: I tried change the integrand from the complicated expression to simply return input. Because now the input is linear, trapezoidal method is suppose to return an exact answer. The output is checked against the expected answer and I finally find one of my bug.



When I use trapezoidal rule to integrate along the imaginary axis, I need to multiply delta by i (the imaginary unit), that allow me to build a more reasonable graph. The result is not correct yet, something else is still wrong, but I moved forward.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this answer to my own question by looking more carefully at the sequence of the generated points.

Cutting the debugging story short, the crux of the problem is that I made a really stupid mistake: The formula should be (w - 50)^(-2/3) w^(-2/3) (w + 50)^(-2/3) instead of ((w - 50)(w + 50))^(-2/3)

With that fixed, I have the correct plot as follow:

[image]

Note the angles! It is now a conformal mapping from the upper half plane to the triangle!

The code is updated on GitHub as well.